# asp.net C# update textbox value without refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website where there are two pages, page1 contain textbox and button1,

if I cliked button1 it will open page2 which contain button2,

if I cliked button2 it will assign value from page2 to the textbox in page1

but the problem is the value will display in the textbox after I refresh page1,

and my question is how I can update textbox value directly without refresh in page1 after I click button2 in page2 like this:

here is my code:

page1 aspx.cs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function openPopup() {

    window.open("page2.aspx", "_blank", "WIDTH=1080,HEIGHT=790,scrollbars=no, menubar=no,resizable=yes,directories=no,location=no");

}
```

```
<asp:button text="clik" id="button1" runat="server" onclientclick="return openPopup()" xmlns:asp="#unknown" style="margin-right:30%" />



    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       if (Session["userID"] != null)
                {
                    txtbox.Text = HttpContext.Current.Session["userID"].ToString();
                }
    }
```

page2:

```
   protected void button2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Session["userID"] = row.Cells[0].Text;
    }
```

Comment: Set AutoPostBack true for Label  and also set UpdateMode property to Conditional

Comment: thanks Samim Hussain I treid your answer but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks everyone I solve it by using session with javascript

Answer (score 0):

we can do this in following way:

1. create a javascript function on page 2, that refresh textbox1 on
   page 1.
2. on button2 click from page 2, using scriptmanager, call
   the function created in step 1 with require param.

So, basically you code be like:

```
 // place this in page2.aspx
 // javascript function to update text box in page 1;
  function UpdateParentText(value){  
     if(typeof(value) != undefined){
        window.opener.document.getElementById("TextBox1").value=value;
      }
   }

  //2. code behind call to the javascript function from page2.cs
  protected void button2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // code behind call to the javascript function. 
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "MyScript", "UpdateParentText('" + row.Cells[0].Text + "'", true);
   }
```

If you are not using AJAX, then use this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MyScript", "UpdateParentText('" + row.Cells[0].Text + "'", true);
```

Comment: thanks Rishu Ranjan for the answer I tried the code but still didn't update TextBox1

Comment: Hi Arater, could you please tell me what is not working? are you able to call the javascript function 'UpdateParentText'.

Comment: I tried the same code but when I click button2 in page 2 the value of textbox1 in pag1 doesn't update dynamically I need to refresh page1 to update textbox1  value

Comment: I get it, but could you tell me if function UpdateParentText is being called or not ?

Comment: it is not called

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", "alert('function is called');", true);
--- can you please try this code. It should show an alert on the page on button click.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

- window.postMessage() — to send the message
- window.addEventListener(“message”,callback) — to receive and process the message

See sample [here](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/javascript-and-window-postmessage-a60c8f6adea9).